# Как перевести файл в массив байтов

Tags: java, файлы

Как перевести файл в массив байтов и наоборот?

Файлом может быть MS Word и Excel или что-то другое.

Также и строку.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Используйте [`Files.readAllBytes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes%28java.nio.file.Path%29) (с Java-7):

```
byte[] array = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName));
```

Answer (score 3):

например так:

```
byte[] fileInArray = new byte[(int)file.length()];
FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream("<файл который хотите преобразовать>");
f.read(fileInArray);
```

Это без использования всякого рода сторонних библиотек. Средствами java.

Comment: \я вот если я пытаюсь из джава класса сделать массив байтов и какой метод мне использовать не знаете?

Comment: @Aslan Kussein с файлами .java точно так же. Если же вам нужно в массив байтов преобразовать объект какого-то класса , то вам необходимо его сериализовать. Очень хороший ресурс на эту тему [здесь](http://www.skipy.ru/technics/serialization.html)

Comment: А вы документацию к [`InputStream.read`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte[]%29) читали? Там вообще-то написано «Reads *some* number of bytes from the input stream and stores them into the buffer array b». А вы даже возвращаемое значение не проверяете. Чтение может прерваться в произвольный момент, и вы никак не узнаете, сколько байт считано по факту.

Comment: @Tagir Valeev никто не мешает обработать ошибку при чтении. Насчет контроля количества считанных байт согласен- в моем способе его нет (а может и не нужен). И все же... Как  вы решали бы эту проблему, при использовании java более взрослых версий?

Comment: Вообще, вероятно, лучше memory-mapping сделать. Это будет быстрее. Если без мемори-мэппинга — воспользовался бы библиотекой или написал бы вручную примерно то же самое, что в `readAllBytes`.

Answer (score 2):

Если интересует самый простой способ, то вам поможет библиотека apache commons io. Там есть готовый метод .toByteArray, который можно применить к файловому потоку ввода/вывода.